# Definition of the rank of infinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, infinity

How is the rank of an infinite matrix defined?  Is it the same as in the finite case, i.e. the number of elements in a basis for some matrix?  How are the dimensionalities of the column and null spaces defined for infinite matrices?  I have searched quite a bit online and have found no discussion of these issues.